# Prometheus server reload rules automatically

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm using the prometheus-community helm chart to deploy prometheus in my cluster.

I know that is possible to configure a custom service discovery for discovering new targets dynamically, this process does not requires a reload operation in Prometheus, see example:

```
      scrape_configs:
    - job_name: 'my-custom-job'
      file_sd_configs:
        - files:
            - '/my/path/targets.json'
          refresh_interval: 5m
```

Is there any similar concept for alerting rules?

I would like to create my custom discovery alerting rules, where I would make some calls, get some rules, validate the rules and store as a json file that will be read by prometheus in a certain period of time and does not requires any reload operation. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

No, if you change the recording rules or the alerting rules, you need to reload the Prometheus by sending SIGHUP to the Prometheus process.

Comment: Example command: # kill -HUP <Prometheus-PID>
# kill -HUP 1234